# Путь к скрипту Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

Необходимо подключить jquery к html файлу для выполнения скрипта по проверке на допустимые символы. Однако, мое решение не работает(ошибок не выдает, просто скрипт не срабатывает), подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я подключил jquery.

[image: структура]

**подключение в html**

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iname').on('input', function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            var pattern = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
            if (pattern.test($(this).val())) {
                $(this).css({
                    'border': '1px solid #ebebeb'
                });
                $('#valid').text('');
            } else {
                $(this).css({
                    'border': '1px solid #ff0000'
                });
                $('#valid').text('Только латинские символы и цифры');
            }
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                'border': '1px solid #ff0000'
            });
            $('#valid').text('Поле не должно быть пустым');
        }
    });
});
    </script>
</head>
```

форма

```
<form method="POST" action="/expsearch">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="iname" th:value="${name}" placeholder="Введите название книги" pattern=".{0,255}" class="form-control"><br>
        <div id="valid"></div><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Найти книги</button>
</form>
```

**конфигурация**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraryWebApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LibraryWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/js/");
    }

}
```

Comment: Откройте консоль разработчика(DevTool) в хроме, вкладку Network и посмотрите, загрузилось ли jquery. Думаю что нет, т.к. путь у вас без указания директории.

Comment: status: 302 у jquery-3.5.1.js

Comment: Значит загрузилось. Следовательно, делайте воспроизводимый пример, потому что большего из вашего кода понять нельзя.

Comment: во вкладке консоль он ругается на $ в $(document).ready(function() 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at expsearch:9"

Comment: Значит не загрузилось. Согласен со @StepanKasyanenko - надо больше деталей.

Comment: добавил код для формы, от проблемы с $ избавился, вынеся 2ой скрипт в отдельный фаил, для него тоже код 302

Comment: Должен быть код 200. Проблема на стороне spring.

Comment: у меня spring security используется, может он как-то доступ отрезает?

Answer (score 0):

Запрос должен быть на:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

На сколько я понял из документации по [конфигурации поставляемых источников](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) все запросы должны включать путь на который делается мапинг.

> For example, to serve resource requests with a URL pattern of
> /resources/** from a public-resources directory within the web
> application root you would use:

```
@Configuration @EnableWebMvc public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/public-resources/"); }

}
```

И они рекоммендуют расширять *WebMvcConfigurerAdapter* вместо реализации интерфейса *WebMvcConfigurer*

Comment: пробовал, эффект такой же  - статус 302

Comment: Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/login' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.   Полагаю,  в spring security дело

Comment: тьфу, и правда если залогиниться то код 200

Answer (score 0):

Было бы неплохо, если бы ты скинул ЛОГИ из консольки браузера.

Я могу предположить, что проблема в Spring, который не всегда охотно находит нужные файлы front-end'а. Попробуй так(тут в коде не трогай ничего, только попробуй переместить все свои файлы `js` и `html` в `templates`, чтобы кроме `templates` не было больше путей):

```java
/**
     * Данный метод помогает Spring обнаруживать пути к файлам
     *
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/");
    }
```